# jQuery Masket Input -> Событие если маска не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код, при котором добавляется класс, если все заполнено верно:

```
$("#user_phone").mask("+7 (999) 999-9999",
    {
       completed: function() {
            $('#btn_submit').addClass("blue");
       }
    }
);
```

Из поля `#user_phone` удалили информацию, маска теперь не работает верно, а класс `blue` у элемента остался. Как его отменить? Т.е. нужно событие на "если не сработала маска".

Answer (score 2):

```js
var $button = $('#btn_submit'),
  options = {
    onComplete: function() {
      $button.addClass("blue");
    },
    onChange: function(val) {

      $button.removeClass("blue");

    }
  };

$("#user_phone").mask("+7 (999) 999-9999", options);
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//raw.githubusercontent.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/v1.13.4/dist/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input id="user_phone" type="text">
<input id="btn_submit" type="submit">
```

Вариант, когда поле только пустое:

```js
var $button = $('#btn_submit'),
  options = {
    onComplete: function() {
      $button.addClass("blue");
    },
    onChange: function(val) {
      if (val === '+') {
        $button.removeClass("blue");
      }
    }
  };

$("#user_phone").mask("+7 (999) 999-9999", options);
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//raw.githubusercontent.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/v1.13.4/dist/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input id="user_phone" type="text">
<input id="btn_submit" type="submit">
```

Comment: А можно вопрос по этой строке `if (val === '+')` подскажите, что за переменная такая val и почему она идентична '+' ?

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов: Особенность плагина. Переменная `val` содержит введное значение в момент его изменения `onChange`. При удалении всех символов из поля, к примеру, backspace-ом, остаётся первый символ, в данном случае, первый символ маски `+`. Почитайте [документацию](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) и "поиграйтесь" с примерами.